# What's wrong with my EF query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a huge problem. I can't figure out what's wrong with my LINQ query. Here is SQL query that gets the job done:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT MIN(DateTime) AS DateTime, ETAG
FROM         dbo.Table
GROUP BY ETAG, LEFT(DateTime, 10)
ORDER BY ETAG
```

This query gives me about 50k results, when executed. I want the same in LINQ. Here is what I tried:

```
from d in Table
group d by new { d.ETAG, Date = d.DateTime.Value.Year + d.DateTime.Value.Month + d.DateTime.Value.Day } into g
orderby g.Key.ETAG
select g.OrderBy(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()
```

When I execute this, it takes few min to be done, and gives me about 9k results. Something is wrong, but I can't figure what. Please, help me get this right...
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the Date property by adding the Year (int), Month (int) and Day (int) together? This is most likely your problem.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @dodjavola Am I correct in thinking that you are using `LEFT` here so that you can group by just the date portion of your `DateTime` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .NET 4 or higher, Entity Framework provides several utility functions specifically for date values.  This may help you get over the hurdle with the first example and prevent you from having to eager load all rows before you group.

```
from d in Table
group d by new { d.ETAG, Date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateTime) } into g
orderby g.Key.ETAG
select g.OrderBy(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, if your aim is to group by just the date portion of the field you could try:

```
from d in Table
let dt = d.DateTime
group d by new { d.ETAG, y = dt.Year, m = dt.Month, d = dt.Day } into g
orderby g.Key.ETAG
select g.OrderBy(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cb58ae5f-5db9-4054-92b6-a1bf63764574/*

Comment: I'm getting timeout exception on this one :(

Comment: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` is only compatible with LINQ to Entities- not Entity Framework.

Comment: LINQ to Entities IS the Entity Framework... From the MSDN: *LINQ to Entities provides Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) support that enables developers to write queries against the Entity Framework* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx)

Comment: @dodjavola Could try and post the SQL that would be generated by this query?  This question outlines a possible method to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 1):

Based on your two queries, the group by in your LINQ statement is fundamentally different because you are not grouping by the actual date, but rather the integer sum of the Year, Month, and Day.

<strike>Instead, try this:</strike>

```
from d in Table
group d by new { d.ETAG, Date = date.DateTime.Value.Date } into g
orderby g.Key.ETAG
select g.OrderBy(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately, due to the limitations of Entity Framework the above query will not work (even though it *is* valid in LINQ to SQL). In fact, there is no efficient parallel to the your SQL query using Entity Framework. The only option to obtain the output you want with a LINQ expression is to capture all of the records with a `.ToList()` prior to grouping and transforming them. Not ideal, but it will work.

```
from d in Table.ToList()
group d by new { d.ETAG, Date = date.DateTime.Value.Date } into g
orderby g.Key.ETAG
select g.OrderBy(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I can't do that way, because I'm getting "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." :(

Comment: @dodjavola Updated answer with a solution.